# scala alternative for using index variable

Tags: scala

Suppose we have matrix, which has basis column and non-basis column. And we need ability to obtain basis part of matrix or non-basis. 
Which colums are bases specified in array declared like `var base: Array[Boolean]`

Currently I'm doing it like:

```
  def getMatrix(matrix: DenseMatrix[Double], pred: Boolean, m: Int, n: Int): DenseMatrix[Double] = {
    var a = DenseMatrix.zeros[Double](m, n)
    var scanPos: Int = 0
    var insertPos: Int = 0
    for (el <- base) {
      if (el == pred) {
        a(::, insertPos) := matrix(::, scanPos)
        insertPos += 1
      }
      scanPos += 1
    }
    return a
  }
```

but this code is ugly and I really hate it. there must be a more elegant solution and i'm asking for it

PS: DenseMatrix class from breeze library and may be considered as 2-D Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if breeze offers a better way to do this, but you could do something like this:

```
  def getMatrix(matrix: DenseMatrix[Double], pred: Boolean, m: Int, n: Int): DenseMatrix[Double] = {
    val data = base
      .zipWithIndex
      .filter(_._1 == pred)
      .map(b => matrix(::, b._2).toArray)
      .flatten

    new DenseMatrix(m, n, data)
  }
```

Something like this should work too:

```
  def getMatrix(matrix: DenseMatrix[Double], pred: Boolean, m: Int, n: Int): DenseMatrix[Double] = {
    val a = DenseMatrix.zeros[Double](m, n)

    for {
      x <- base.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 == pred).zipWithIndex
      ((el, matrixIndex), newIndex) = x
    } yield a(::, newIndex) := matrix(::, matrixIndex)

    a
  }
```